# Start playling Lottie once collection view is changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, lottie

I have problem with lottie animations, I have some kind of onboarding on my app and what I would like to achive is to everytime view in collectionview is changed, to start my animation, I have 4 pages and 4 different lottie animations. Currently if I call animation.play() function, once app is started, all of my animations are played at the same time, so once I get to my last page, animation is over. And I want my lottie to be played only once, when view is shown.

**This is my cell**

```
class IntroductionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var subtitleDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var animationView: AnimationView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
    
public func configure(with data: IntroInformations) {
    let animation = Animation.named(data.animationName)
    
    title.text = data.title
    subtitleDescription.text = data.description
    animationView.animation = animation
}

static func nib() -> UINib {
    return UINib(nibName: "IntroductionCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
  }
}
```

**This is how my collection view is set up**

```
extension IntroductionViewController {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    pages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "IntroductionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! IntroductionCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.configure(with: pages[indexPath.row])
    cell.animationView.loopMode = .loop
    cell.animationView.play()
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollPos = scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width
    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(floorf(Float(scrollPos)))
    
    let n = pageControl.numberOfPages
    
    if self.pageControl.currentPage == n - 1 {
        continueButton.isHidden = false
    } else {
        continueButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if let cell = cell as? IntroductionCollectionViewCell {
     cell.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
     cell.animationView.play()
  }
```

this is the answer, I need to check is cell once is loaded my cell where lottie animation is

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collectionViewDelegate willDisplay and didEndDisplaying methods to start/stop the animations. And not when configuring the cell. - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate
If you want the animation to run only once dont use the loop option.

Answer (score 0):

scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation use this method on UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and implement the functionality for pause or play the lottie.

hope it would help.